# Facebook status not updated. Error 403, authentication error, SocialAuthException in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, socialauth

I have created an Android application, in that the authorization with Facebook is done fine, but when I tap on the update status button it shows exception. It returns status code 403.

Code is:

```
if (providerName.equalsIgnoreCase("facebook") 
        {
            try 
            {
                adapter.updateStory(
                        "Hello SocialAuth Android" + System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        "AAA",
                        "BBB",
                        "CCC.",
                        "DDD", "EEE",
                        new MessageListener());
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {               
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So the code is 403 or 400?

Comment: Its 403. See my updated question

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925620/facebook-links-to-my-site-resolve-as-403-forbidden 
Have you tried searching anything? Stackoverflow, Google?

Comment: Yes i had preffered http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr it works in twitter, LinkedIn, Yahoo, Google+ and all other but doesnt work on Facebook

Comment: Hi, please download the latest sdk. Now socialauth android uses native flow.

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the SocialAuth Wiki I found a current bug matching your description:

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=175

So you're not alone with your problem. You could provide any more information in their issue tracker to help and to indicate the severity of the problem.

But besides that I'm afraid you'll just have to wait - or consider fixing the bug in the otherwise open source library on your own.

---

You could also check whether the original Java implementation or the .Net port are experiencing the same problem; if not the code from those libraries might help to find a solution.

Comment: Strangely, their sample works. However, as soon as I replace their app keys with my own, everything breaks and I get this error.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 403 `Authentication Error` that clearly means that your app is presently not *authorized* to publish on Facebook profile of the user.

There is some problem the way you are trying to use Facebook APIs. I would suggest you to the latest Facebook SDK for Android as some of the older methods may be deprecated. Let me tell you the approach for doing this right way. (I recently implemented latest Facebook SDK)

- **You need a permission**

There are some specific permissions that you require to do some specific operations with Facebook SDK. For example, You need `publish_actions` permission if you want your app to post status on user's profile.

[Check Out](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) It says,

`For example, the publish_actions permission lets you post to a person's Facebook Timeline.`

- **How to get Permissions**

You need to show the user a login button which will ask him to do login with his facebook account and notifying the user what your app may do with his Facebook profile. It will show the permissions. In your case you need to add a login button with `publish_actions` permission. Once the user accepts it, your app becomes **authorized** to post status.

[Complete Tutorial is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0) for doing the login process of Facebook with permissions.

You will need to do the following,

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setFragment(this);
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_likes", "user_status", "publish_actions"));
return view;
```

So you can see we are asking the user to give you the publish_actions permission. It is not mandatory to include `user_likes` or `user_status` permissions. You can remove them if you don't need them.

- **Next what after login**

After the user logs in, you get an `authentication token` in your `session` with Facebook. So now you can use that to publish on user's profile.

- **How to post**

Now there are many ways to publish posts or status on Facebook. The first one I would like to discuss is using the `Graph API`

[Check this link for more details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/status#publishing)

Here is somewhat code, you can use to publish to facebook.

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

new Request(
    session,
    "/me/feed",
    null,
    HttpMethod.POST,
        new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            }
        }
).executeAsync();
```

or You can go through [this tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph) also.

**NOTE**

You do also need to create developer account with facebook and add your app to its dashboard, generate an app_id and mention the same in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

[More Info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0#config)

Comment: The question is about the third-party library socialauth-android, not the Facebook SDK.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Okay, got it. But I think it is better to use Facebook SDK for Facebook purposes. It gives you more control over everything. From the response to the question, we can see how popular it is to use third party library. Anyways, I believe all my efforts to write the answer will help someone someday.

Comment: Your answer here is definitely appreciated. Thanks for the details for using the Facebook SDK. In my particular situation, I am using socialauth-android because I want to support multiple social networks.

Comment: @Skynet I hope so. You can let me know if you face any problem here. or post a new question.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge about this: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/the-new-facebook-login/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the socialauth-4.4.jar with below jar file url link. And check Facebook sharing will work.

Download jar file from

https://socialauth-android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1880009000&name=test_social.jar&token=ABZ6GAeEabJhhI5PtmSHn7pA8pcsk6s_Zw%3A1415373843808